# Autoscaling Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, database, cpu-usage, autoscaling, azure-sql

I'm looking to set up some type of method to **autoscale (vertically) my Azure SQL Databases based on CPU or some other performance metric**. My environment is in **govcloud** and I don't see any options for autoscale. I've create a **logic app** that will scale up and down at set times but this doesn't help when **performance fluctuates on a given day**.

If somebody knows of a way to trigger the databases to autoscale when cpu reaches a certain percentage I would appreciate any help/guidance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way built into Azure SQL to autoscale, however, you can configure performance alerts using Azure Monitor that look at CPU or other metrics. When you create an alert you define an action group to trigger when the threshold is breached, this can notify, but it can also call a Logic App, Function or Automation runbook. Using this you can trigger something to occur on a performance threshold.